# Convert a Number in a String to a Number that has Commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

`"11' - Add $1,200"`

I need a variable like this from that:

`variable = 1200`

How would I strip that number out, basically all the numbers after the $ stripping out commas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
parseFloat(variable.replace(/.*\$/,'').replace(/[^.\d]/g,''))
```

The first call to `replace` removes everything up to (and including) the last dollar sign in the string.  The second removes all non-numeric and non decimal point characters.  `parseFloat` converts the result to a number.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = "11' - Add $1,200";
var split_array = input.split("$");
var dollar = parseInt(split_array[1].replace(",",""));
alert(dollar);
```

Comment: Use radix with parseInt! 077 is assumed octal, which is 63. And ES5 makes radix mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

Just a demo.... but I'm late it seems. http://jsfiddle.net/L4VNr/

```
$('.money').each(function(){
   $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/.*\$/,'').replace(/,/g,'') );
});
```